# Appending new data to existing associative array

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I've been working on Python for last few months and I encountered this problem.
So, I have a dictionary which contains only keys and no values.

```
{'_id' : None, 'game' : None, 'viewers' : None ....}
```

And I want to add data which are in the list. 
For example,

```
[123456, 'StarCraft 2', 300, ....]
```

As you might guess, the order of elements inside the list corresponds to the order of keys inside the dict.
I think using for loop is the solution but I couldn't come up with a good one.

---

Extra question: 
The dict above is now dictionaries inside a list.
And, I want to add exactly same dictionary with same keys and new values every time I get a new list of data.

```
[{'_id': 001, 'game':'StarCraft 2', 'viewers':300, ...}, 
 {'_id': 002, 'game':'Tetiris', 'viewers': 30, ...},
... ]
```

How do I do that?

Thanks, Python friends!!

Comment: You cannot be certain of the order of the keys in the dict. Thus, this is, at best, fragile, at worst plain wrong.

Comment: Further, how come you have a list of data to begin with. That sounds odd.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you cannot do that with a dict because the order is not conserved. But you can use the class `OrderedDict` as shown here: [Python dictionary, how to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

What you could do is have a list with your keys to keep track of the order:

```
my_keys = ['_id', 'game', 'viewers']
for index, elt in enumerate(my_data):
     my_dict[my_keys[index]] = elt
```

Comment: "because the order is not conserved". Now it is, but only as a side effect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: True, since 3.6 it is conserved but it might not stay that way: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html